# Fetching the echo of a PHP file in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, fetch, use-state

I'm totally new to ReactJS and freshly completed my tutorial and now I'm working around with React. I started with just making a PHP file echo "Hello" and React.js fetching that response and displaying it on the website but it doesn't seem to work at all.

My PHP code:

```php
<?PHP
  echo "Hello!";
?>
```

My React.js code:

```
const [data, newData] = useState(null);
useEffect(() => {
  fetch(//MY .php file link, NOT API just a php file echoing hello)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(newData);
  });
        
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        { data }
      </div>
    </>
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first `.then()` of `fetch`, when you try to extract the JSON content from the response by using the `json()` method, you should use the `.text()` method instead as you're returning a simple string from your server, not a JSON object. Once you returned this text, you can update the state in the second `.then()`.

Don't forget to include a dependency array in your `useEffect`, as without it you will always trigger another render after it runs. If you add an empty array as a dependency, it will only fetch on page load.

```
function App() {
  const [data, newData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(URL)
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((response) => newData(response));
  }, []);

  return <div>{data ? data : 'No data yet...'}</div>;
}
```